# JsonUtility how to break json into new line

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I been follow the tutorial from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPhtjcNTMN8) video.

The tutorial source code can be found at [here](https://github.com/xenfinity-software)...

I have a problem of my Json data all been stored in 1 single line,

[image]

I want the data break into new line for single object data

[image]

Here the code for the Json tutorial

Actor file

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;

public class Actor : MonoBehaviour {

public ActorData data = new ActorData();

public string name = "Tile";

string newline = "\n";

public void StoreData()
{
    data.name = name;
    data.pos = transform.position;
}

public void LoadData()
{
    name = data.name;
    transform.position = data.pos;

}

public void ApplyData()
{
    SaveData.AddActorData(data);
}

void OnEnable()
{
    SaveData.OnLoaded += LoadData;
    SaveData.OnBeforeSave += StoreData;
    SaveData.OnBeforeSave += ApplyData;

}

void OnDisable()
{
    SaveData.OnLoaded -= LoadData;
    SaveData.OnBeforeSave -= StoreData;
    SaveData.OnBeforeSave -= ApplyData;
}

}

[Serializable]
 public class ActorData
 {
    public string name;
public Vector2 pos;
 }
```

save data file

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Xml.Serialization;
 using System.IO;

 public class SaveData
 {

public static ActorContainer actorContainer = new ActorContainer();

public delegate void SerializeAction();
public static event SerializeAction OnLoaded;
public static event SerializeAction OnBeforeSave;

public static void Load(string path)
{
    actorContainer = LoadActors(path);

    foreach (ActorData data in actorContainer.actors)
    {
        GameController.CreateActor(data, GameController.playerPath,
            data.pos, Quaternion.identity);
    }

    OnLoaded();

    ClearActorList();
}

public static void Save(string path, ActorContainer actors)
{
    OnBeforeSave();

    //ClearSave(path);
    SaveActors(path, actors);

    ClearActorList();
}

public static void AddActorData(ActorData data)
{
    actorContainer.actors.Add(data);
}

public static void ClearActorList()
{
    actorContainer.actors.Clear();
}

private static ActorContainer LoadActors(string path)
{
    string json = File.ReadAllText(path);

    return JsonUtility.FromJson<ActorContainer>(json);
}

private static void SaveActors(string path, ActorContainer actors)
{
    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(actors);

    StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path);
    sw.Close();
    File.WriteAllText(path, json);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two overloads for the [`JsonUtility.ToJson`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.ToJson.html) function:

- `public static string ToJson(object obj);`
- `public static string ToJson(object obj, bool prettyPrint);`

Use the second one and pass `true` to it. It will format the output for readability making the json separated into lines.

Just replace `string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(actors);` with `string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(actors, true);`

If you are not satisfied with the result, use  [*Newtonsoft.Json*](https://github.com/SaladLab/Json.Net.Unity3D) for Unity and format the json like this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(actors);
string newLineJson = JValue.Parse(json).ToString(Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: oh gosh u save my day, i trying figuring out by insert "\n" anyway

Comment: Sometimes, reading the doc of an API you are using is really important and helpful. If I didn't read the doc when `JsonUtility` newly came out, I  wouldn't know you could do this either.